# How can I extract a substring from a matching line in a file?

Tags: linux, shell, sed, grep

I use:

```
cat display.txt | sed -e 's/...\(.*\).../\1/g'
```

to get string between("..."). But, it gives me this result which is full content of the file. How can I extract just `"hhgggeeee"` from this?

```
= New Index: 98:4F:EE:06:0B:03 (BR/EDR,UART,hci0)               
[hci0] 0.595705 > ACL Data RX: Handle 12 flags 0x02 dlen 19                    
[hci0] 11.420307 Channel: 64 len 15 [PSM 0 mode 0] {chan 0}     
1b ef 17 68 68 67 67 67 65 65 65 65 0d 0a 8f 
...hhgggeeee... > HCI Event: Mode Change (0x14) plen 6 [hci0] 11.923905
Status: Success (0x00) Handle: 12 Mode: Active (0x00)
Interval: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
```

Comment: you should put 4 spaces before each line of your codes.

Comment: `sed 's/^.*[ ][.][.][.]\([^.]*\).*$/\1/' filename` (presuming there is a `' '` before the `...hhgggeeee...`)

Comment: Or `sed -n '/\.\.\./s/\.\.\.\(.*\)\.\.\..*/\1/p' display.txt`

Comment: i got the right line with and  i loose thoose three points where i supposed to cut the string

Comment: sed -n '/\.\.\./s/\.\.\.\(.*\)\.\.\..*/\1/p' display.txt

Comment: 1b ef 17 68 68 67 67 67 65 65 65 65 0d 0a 8f             hhgggeeee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ sed -n 's/.*\.\{3\}\(.*\)\.\{3\}.*/\1/p' file
hhgggeeee
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `perl` one liner for this:

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if /^\.\.\.(.*)\.\.\./' display.txt
```

For your file, it outputs:

```
hhgggeeee
```

Comment: that's not working. i got the line which contain ...string.. the second command has empty result

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sed command. Try the below command.

```
cat dis.txt|sed -n 's/\.\.\.\([^\.]\+\)\.\.\..*/\1/gp'
```

Or use can use the grep command also.

```
cat dis.txt|grep -o '\.\.\.\([^\.]\+\)\.\.\.'
```

The both are gives the same output. The output is

```
hhgggeeee
```